# Ubuntu core 14.04 image

Tags: 14.04, arm, ubuntu-core, beagleboard

Is there anywhere Ubuntu Core 14.04 armhf image for BeagleBone Black to download. I found many tar.gz files but that are filesystems only. I am looking for img file.

I have many problems with Snappy and all the other BBB OS-es are taking too much space and RAM. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's no image for 14.04, to get the current (15.04) img run the following commands:

```
$ wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/vivid/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf+bbb.img.xz
$ unxz ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf+bbb.img.xz
```

Comment: My problem is Snappy...I can't create snappy application that uses bonescript so I wanted to try something normal but minimal.